# How to convert the proper class in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I tried to convert the class from character to date it showing an error
Error in charToDate(x) :
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

```
dput(my_data$exit_date)
c("0000-00-00", "2019-08-25", "2019-12-31", "2020-04-02", "2020-09-15", 
"0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "2019-12-08", "0000-00-00", 
"2020-11-30", "2020-09-01", "0000-00-00", "2020-02-15", "2020-07-24", 
"2021-03-22", "2020-07-03", "2020-03-26", "2020-02-24", "2019-05-15", 
"0000-00-00", "2020-01-28", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", 
"0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "2021-03-22", "2021-03-25", 
"2021-03-22", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", 
"0000-00-00")

my_data$exit_date <- as.Date(my_data$exit_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the format of the date. Error is probably because it can't guess from the initial date of 0s.

```
d1 <- c("0000-00-00", "2019-08-25", "2019-12-31", "2020-04-02", "2020-09-15", 
  "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "2019-12-08", "0000-00-00", 
  "2020-11-30", "2020-09-01", "0000-00-00", "2020-02-15", "2020-07-24", 
  "2021-03-22", "2020-07-03", "2020-03-26", "2020-02-24", "2019-05-15", 
  "0000-00-00", "2020-01-28", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", 
  "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "2021-03-22", "2021-03-25", 
  "2021-03-22", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", 
  "0000-00-00")

as.Date(d1, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Seeing as you tagged this a `lubridate` (which I'd always use anyway) here's how you would do it in that.

```
lubridate::ymd(d1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer but i have one doubt why the 00 are automatically turned to NA

Comment: @Fariya there is no year 0, nor month 0 in any year, nor day 0 in any month, so it cannot be a real date.